# How can I prevent a piece of code running during deserialization?

Tags: foreign-keys, deserialization, code-first, postsharp

I have the following code leveraging PostSharp to automatically set a property (a foreign key) when its navigation property (tagged with the ForeignKeyAttribute) is set.

The code is extremely slow when deserializing a large number of entities so I want to know if there is any way I can prevent the code from running during deserialization.

The code still has a few holes in it, I'm still working on it, but I'm using entity framework code first in a disconnected environment and don't have the dbcontext to look after this for me.

```
[Serializable]
public class ForeignKeySynchronisationAttribute : LocationInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            var foreignKeyIdSet = false;
            var entity = args.Instance;
            var propertyInfo = args.Location.PropertyInfo;

            if (typeof(BaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType))
            {
                // First look for metadata defined ForeignKeyAttribute
                var metadata =
                    entity.GetType()
                          .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true)
                          .OfType<MetadataTypeAttribute>()
                          .FirstOrDefault();

                if (metadata != null)
                {
                    var metadataProperty = metadata.MetadataClassType.GetProperty(propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name);

                    if (metadataProperty != null)
                    {
                        var foreignKeyAttribute = metadataProperty.GetCustomAttributes<ForeignKeyAttribute>().First();

                        if (foreignKeyAttribute != null)
                        {
                            var foreignKeyIdPropertyInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperty(foreignKeyAttribute.Name);

                            foreignKeyIdPropertyInfo.SetValue(entity, ((BaseEntity)args.Value).PrimaryKey);
                            foreignKeyIdSet = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Then look for normally defined ForeignKeyAttribute
                if (!foreignKeyIdSet)
                {
                    var foreignKeyAttribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes<ForeignKeyAttribute>().First();

                    if (foreignKeyAttribute != null)
                    {
                        var foreignKeyIdPropertyInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperty(foreignKeyAttribute.Name);
                        foreignKeyIdPropertyInfo.SetValue(entity, ((BaseEntity)args.Value).PrimaryKey);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            base.OnSetValue(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note I've since accomplished what I required via a different method.

Cheers

Craig